# Can you see the arena/fight limits when fighting an epic boss?

Tags: assassins-creed-odyssey

In Assassin's Creed Odyssey (PC) I'm trying to fight the Hind of Keryneia, but I keep accidentally leaving the fight "boundaries" as I dodge his attacks. Is there some way to see what the fight boundaries are for these boss fights? Since I can't figure out where the fight "limits" are, the enemy ends up regenerating before I manage to get back into the "arena".

To be clear, this isn't about the Hind of Keryneia in specific, but about all of these "boss fights" which take place in a limited geographical area.

Comment: In the world they're usually bounded geographically by cliffs, rivers or other similar features.